# Black screen on every python app after changing settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

i'm new to kivy and followed a tutorial for the screenmanager with ActionBar.
In the ActionBar was a button with the function "app.open_settings()" [here is a link to the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html#kivy.uix.settings.Settings).

I played around a bit with the settings, changed the screen rotation, clicked on apply but nothing changed.

Now when i run the python code, i see a black screen which i need to forcefully exit with Alt+F4.

Another python code i tried (in the same workspace but different main.py and .kv-file) also just shows a black screen. It worked previously.
If i press Alt+Tab i can see in the small window that the program is rotated 270°, but since its just a black screen i cant change the settings back.

Any help is very appreciated. I will post the code here, but i don't know if it will help

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.lang import Builder


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class CrimePrevention(BoxLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Kivy ScreenManager & ActionBar Demo'

    def build(self):
        return CrimePrevention()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<CrimePrevention>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    
    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        WelcomeScreen:
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    ActionView:
        id: ActionView

        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:

        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: "spinner"
            text: "Jump to Screen"

            ActionButton:
                text: "Crime Prediction"
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
            ActionButton:
                text: "Forum"
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
            ActionButton:
                text: "Probable Suspect"
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
        
        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'App'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press: app.open_settings()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()
        
        ActionGroup:
            id: File_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'File'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Open'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Save'

<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
    title: ''
    with_previous: False
    app_icon: ''
    app_icon_width: 0
    app_icon_height: 0
    size_hint_x: None
    width: len(self.title)*10

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome Screen'
        font_size: sp(50)

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    Label:
        text: 'First Screen'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Predict Crime'
            font_size: 50
        
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Back to Main Menu'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current = 'first'
```

Comment: You may have accidentally over-written your kivy config file. You can safely remove the config file, since it will be re-created if missing. The config file is in your home directory in `.kivy/config.ini`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks a lot, this was the correct solution. I was honestly surprised that i couldnt find anything about this problem.